# cannot install "conky" due to missing dependencies such as "libgdk-pixbuf" im running the latest version of Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, conky

I'm trying to do is install conky and following every tutorial I can and can not get anything use full due too having problems downloading or something needing some dependency

I'm stuck and lost and new and really mad at this point due to following every tutorial and getting lost again

When I run `sudo apt-get -y install conky-cli` it returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 conky-all : Conflicts: conky-cli but 1.12.2-1 is to be installed
 conky-cli : Conflicts: conky-all but 1.12.2-1 is to be installed
 conky-manager : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: conky but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: p7zip-full but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: imagemagick
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try to install `libgdk-pixbuf` with:

```
sudo apt -y install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 conky-manager : Depends: conky but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: p7zip-full but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: imagemagick
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0 (>= 2.40.2-2build4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: sorry for the awfull look i tried to make it profesional but that didnt work out

Comment: I know how frustrating these dependency issues are. I think we've all been there. Since this isn't coding/programing related, you may have better luck asking over at http://askubuntu.com (it's a stackexchange site that is focussed entirely on Ubuntu).  I'm sure folks over there have experience getting conky up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what tutorial you're following that says to install `conky-cli`. Most of what I'm seeing refers to installation of `conky-all`. Try entering `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install conky-all` to install, as discussed at https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-system-monitoring-with-conky-widgets.